# Why I get the error fail to read the header from "-" only when using nextflow?

Tags: bioinformatics, nextflow

I keep getting this error when running the workflow. But when entering the work directory and running bash .command.run there is no error with the command.

```
process align {
   //Docker Image
  container = 'quay.io/biocontainers/mulled-v2-fe8faa35dbf6dc65a0f7f5d4ea12e31a79f73e40:8110a70be2bfe7f75a2ea7f2a89cda4cc7732095-0'
  
  input:
  tuple val(sampleId), val(path),path(read1), path(read2)
  tuple path(file1),path(file2)
  
  exec:
  String strBam = sampleId + '.bam'
  
  script:
  """
  bwa mem -v 0 $params.align_ref/hg19.fa $file1 $file2 | samtools view -Sb -u > $strBam
  """
}
```

Command error:

> WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match
> the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform
> was requested   [main_samview] fail to read the header from "-".

I can't figure out why it's getting errors when running through nextflow.

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to run these amd64 built containers on a Apple M1? If there are no native ARM builds you could switch to, then maybe the M1 should be able to emulate it with a bit of coercion to docker: `export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64`

Comment: thanks. It pointed me to a direction. The setting that I need to do in order to get rid of the warning is using the setting `docker.runOptions = '--platform linux/amd64'` in the nextflow.config file

Answer (score 1):

Samtools is just complaining about a missing input file:

```
[main_samview] fail to read the header from "-".
```

The problem is that `bwa mem` is failing to produce a SAM file because the reference directory specified using `params.align_ref` does not exist inside the container. Unless a file or directory is specified using the input [`path`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#input-type-path) qualifier, Nextflow will not know to stage the file/directory into the process working directory when the job is run. The solution is ensure we stage our file inputs using the `path` qualifier and avoid accessing files outside of the process working directory. For example:

```
params.reads = '/path/to/fastqs/*_R{1,2}.fastq.gz'
params.ref_fasta = '/path/to/reference/hg19.fa'

bwa_idx_name = file(params.ref_fasta).name
bwa_idx_path = file(params.ref_fasta).parent


process align {
    
    tag { sampleId }

    input:
    tuple val(sampleId), path(fastqs)
    path bwa_index

    output:
    tuple val(sampleId), path("${sampleId}.bam")

    script:
    """
    bwa mem -t ${task.cpus} "${bwa_index}/${bwa_idx_name}" ${fastqs} |
    samtools view -bo "${sampleId}.bam"
    """
}

workflow {
    
    reads = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.reads )

    align( reads, bwa_idx_path )
}
```

And the following `nextflow.config`:

```
params {

    outdir = './results'
}

process {

    shell = [ '/bin/bash', '-euo', 'pipefail' ]

    withName: 'align' {
        container = 'quay.io/biocontainers/mulled-v2-fe8faa35dbf6dc65a0f7f5d4ea12e31a79f73e40:8110a70be2bfe7f75a2ea7f2a89cda4cc7732095-0'
        cpus = 4

        publishDir = [
            path: "${params.outdir}/align",
            mode: 'copy',
        ]
    }
}

docker {

    enabled = true
    runOptions = '--platform linux/amd64'
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.1
Launching `main.nf` [thirsty_gilbert] DSL2 - revision: b4e6fb4eb6
executor >  local (3)
[12/ff2061] process > align (sample1) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
```